# Use only one component in my web

Tags: angular

I have two custom components:

*Component1*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-custom-component1',
    templateUrl: './my-custom-component1.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-custom-component1.css']
})
export class MyCustomComponent1 {
    constructor() {
        console.log('myCustomComponent1');
    }
}
```

*Component2*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-custom-component2',
    templateUrl: './my-custom-component2.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-custom-component2.css']
})
export class MyCustomComponent2 {
    constructor() {
        console.log('myCustomComponent2');
    }
}
```

I use *Component1* in my root component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<my-custom-component1></my-custom-component1>`
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I have in a website, several html files. I want use this angular app in one page.

I do in *file01.html*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>file01</title>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine, but...

In another page I want use the *Component2*. 
How can I use it? I have been trying this, but without success.

*file02.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>file02</title>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <my-custom-component2></my-custom-component2>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to bootstrap with `my-custom-component2` on the other page. I believe you have something like this: `platformBrowserDynamic()
        .bootstrapModule(AppComponent);` You have to repeat the same for `MyCustomComponent2` on other page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the bootstrap option and implement `ngDoBootstrap()` method on your root module yourself.  In order to conditionally bootstrap components just do a `querySelector` before calling `appRef.bootstrap(SomeComponent);` to check whether the component is already on the page.

So your module could look like:

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ 
    AppRootComponent,  // `app-root` selector
    MyCustomComponent1,
    MyCustomComponent2 // `my-custom-component2` selector
  ],
  entryComponents: [ 
    AppRootComponent,  // this is required because we need to have 
    MyCustomComponent2 // host factory for bootstrapped components
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
    if(document.querySelector('app-root')) {
      appRef.bootstrap(AppRootComponent);
    }
    if(document.querySelector('my-custom-component2')) {
      appRef.bootstrap(MyCustomComponent2);
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/YyYbH756ujpBxM8Kyu8M?p=preview)**

To see how it works just remove `app-root` tag from index.html and add `my-custom-component2`